# JavaScript Date constructor creating different dates depending on zero padding?

Tags: javascript, date

In Chrome 34.0.1847.131 when I open the console and enter the following:

```
new Date('2014-05-14');
```

I get the following:

> Tue May 13 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

[image: new Date('2014-05-14')]

Huh? It's one day early! What about if I remove the 0-padding from `05`?

```
new Date('2014-5-14');
```

> Wed May 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

[image: new Date('2014-5-14')]

Am I going insane? What's going on here?

Man, it's too early for this...

Comment: In Firefox 27.0.1 I get the correct date for the first, and `Invalid Date` for the second.

Comment: Your first result is correct: `Tue May 13 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400` *is* `Tue May 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT`.

Comment: Ah, timezones. Of course...

Comment: But why is this different between `05` and `5`?

Comment: Because the `Date()` constructor delegates to [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) when passed a string, and `2014-5-14` is neither a valid RFC2822 nor a valid ISO 8601 representation.

Comment: In that case Firefox's handling makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is, of course, Timezones. As pointed out by [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/frederic-hamidi):

> `Tue May 13 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400` *is* `Tue May 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT`.

The second string passed to the `Date` constructor is not valid per RFC2822 nor ISO 8601.